# JQuery programming not Working?

Tags: jquery, html

I made this program to hide and unhide a message on a webpage. It is hidding an unhiding the message but i also inted to chane the text on the button but it's not changing why.

> The HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="hide" id="toggle_message" />
    <p id="message">You can see this paragraph</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> The jQuery Code:

```
$('#toggle_message').click(function() {

    var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
    $('#message').toggle('fast');

    if (value=='Hide') {
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Show');
    } else if (value=='Show') {
        $('#toggle_message').attr('value', 'Hide');
    }

});
```

Sorry guys I found the problem the value for the button was not correct

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#toggle_message').click(function() {

var value = $('#toggle_message').attr('value');
$('#message').toggle('fast');

if (this.value=="Hide") this.value = "Show";
else this.value = "Hide";

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisG87/uo6zyudu/)

This should work for you. Fiddle can show it working :).

Comment: Not true at all. You can change the value back to hide and change the jquery to hide and it will still work. And the OP has the same value in the post. So what is the problem?